# how to Display values in TextView in android through http

Tags: android

i want to display value of lat and lng that are in my database it returns only 1 or 0 when                                          condition is true plz give me a solution that shows  multi values of lat and lng in textview

```
     here is my code:


   public class Map extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
             TextView Test;

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maptest);

        status();

               }
     public void status() {
    int locationCount =locationCount() ;
    for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++)
    {
     double Latt = Lat();
     double Lngg = Lng();

     Test=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
     String lat = new Double(Latt).toString();
     String lng = new Double(Lngg).toString();
     Test.setText(lng+ lat);
    }

}


 public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
    {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     String line = null;
     try {
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line + "\n");
      }
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     finally {
      try {
       is.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     return sb.toString();
    }

      public static double Lng()
        {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/Lng");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             return 0;
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return 0;
     }

    }
     public static double Lat()
       {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/Lat");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             return 0;
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return 0;
     }

    }

    public static int locationCount()
    {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/locationCount");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             return 0;
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return 0;
     }

    }

   }
```

i want to display value of lat and lng that are in my database it returns only 1 or 0 when                                          condition is true plz give me a solution that shows  multi values of lat and lng in textview

```
 Thank you so much in advance :(
```

Comment: You have to place your http requests in an AsyncTask or thread. You will have a NetworkOnMainThreadException now. And in all functions the catch block will return a 0. Look in the LogCat for all those errors. Don't thank in advance but afterwards please.

Comment: im new in android so can you tell me how to use http requests in an AsyncTask or thread in my this code plz.

Comment: You can find many examples on this site. Search or just read the pages here.

Comment: i unable to place after searching i need this code urgently plz edit my code :'(

Comment: class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>        {
 

 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      publishProgress("Loading contents..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
      String resp = "error";
  try {
 
     
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    
    //Connect to the server
    HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/LatLng");

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.maptest);
         Test=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
         AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
         runner.execute();

Comment: Please do not post code in comments as it is unreadable as you can see yourself. Just edit your post and add new code block(s).